# I want to print dynamic values in visualforce page with if condition. How can I do this?

Tags: visualforce, formula

```
If(Service == 'Tenant Referencing', 'References ','Policies ') + 'processed : '+ lstInvoice[0].TR_Count__c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expression language in VF for condition based rendering of data

```
{!IF(service == 'Tenant' || service == 'Reference'),'If-True-Display-This','If-False-Display-This'}
```